# AngularDart - Way to aggregate statically defined child component with dynamic once

Tags: web, design-patterns, dart, single-page-application, angular-dart

I would like to aggregate statically defined child components with dynamical once that might be sourced from the stream. I want a generic way to define carousel in this carousel where I can have a typed collection of components. The collection can be defined statically or dynamically. Below is an example:

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/core.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';


/**
 *
 */
@Component(
    selector: 'md-text',
    styleUrls: const ['md_text.css'],
    template: '<li>{{name}}</li>',
    directives: const [
      materialDirectives,
    ]
)
class TextComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input()
  String name;

  TextComponent([this.name]);

  TextComponent.withName(String name)
      : this(name);

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}

@Component(
    selector: 'md-texts',
    styleUrls: const ['text_component.css'],
    template: '<ol><md-text *ngFor="let component of components" [name]="component.name"></md-text><ng-content></ng-content></ol>',
    directives: const [
      CORE_DIRECTIVES,
      materialDirectives,
      TextComponent
    ]
)
class TextsComponent<TextComponent> implements OnInit
{
  Set<T> _components;

  Set<T> get components => _components;

  addComponent(T component){
    this._components.add(component);
  }

  removeComponent(T component) {
    this._components.remove(component);
  }

  TextsComponent() {
    this._components = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
    TextComponent declarativeChannel = new TextComponent.withName("United States");
    this.addComponent(declarativeChannel);
  }

  @override
  ngOnInit(){
    print("I am here");
  }
}
```

in my dashboard component, I have statically defined the usage as follows:

```
<md-texts>
    <md-text [name]="'Liberty'"></md-text>
    <md-text [name]="'Life'"></md-text> 
<md-texts>
```

The display is as following
United States
Liberty
Life

What I want to do is have the "Liberty" and "Life" also be aggregated to my component collection, so I can control it with the next and previous button. I also only want to render them when their index is called for.  What is the best way to do this in AngularDart.

I found a similar question with old version but with older version [How to reference child component from its parent in AngularDart in AD 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764718/how-to-reference-child-component-from-its-parent-in-angulardart-in-ad-1-0-0) and [How to reference child component from its parent in AngularDart in AD 1.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764718/how-to-reference-child-component-from-its-parent-in-angulardart-in-ad-1-0-0)

Regards,  Hopefully i have explained my problem and i will get clear direction on what is the correct way of addressing this design issue.

Comment: I don't really understand what you ask for, but it might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , my question is little different, I know how to use dynamic components.  But the question is how can a static component definition be detected (discovered) by the parent component. In my case Texts is parent component Text is child components.  When i use it statically in markup how can they be added to my collection components in above example? If you look at the code i have injecting United States instance via constructor and Life, Liberty thru markup, the components collection is only aware of United States how can i make it aware of Life and Liberty.

Comment: I think you need an approach like shown in my linked answer. Just add them dynamically, then you can control them. You can't move around components added statically (still not sure I understand what you try to accomplish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ViewChildren` and `@ContentChildren` to query for child components. `@ViewChildren` will query for components declared in your template, whereas `@ContentChildren` will query for components projected into an `<ng-content>` in your template.

It's worth mentioning that in your example, your dynamic `TextComponent` is being created twice. First, you create one in your constructor, then again when you declare a `<md-text>` in your template. This means the instance you're keeping a reference to, isn't actually the component rendered in your view. To avoid this, don't bother creating the instance imperatively. Just keep a model of the data needed to create them, then pass that through inputs in your template where you declare the components. You can then use `@ViewChildren` to query for those components you've created.

Here's an example

```
@Component(
  selector: 'md-texts',
  template: '''
    <ol>
      <md-text *ngFor="let text of texts" [text]="text"></md-text>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ol>
  ''',
  directives: const [NgFor, TextComponent],
)
class TextsComponent {
  /// Text that was projected through `<ng-content>`.
  @ContentChildren(TextComponent)
  QueryList<TextComponent> contentTexts;

  /// Text that was created in our view from our model.
  @ViewChildren(TextComponent)
  QueryList<TextComponent> viewTexts;

  /// Data model for the text in our view.
  final List<String> texts = [
    ...
  ];
}
```

Alternatively, you could render all of the `<md-text>` from a single source of data in your view, and rely on passing in a model for the static data rather than projecting the components.

Comment: your answer was correct, I wish there was a way to aggregate both viewchild and contentchild as one, but I do agree with your comments. Ideally, it would just make sense to have all the components be rendered from a single data input list or a stream.